# Counterexample: if $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure then $\frac{1}{f_n}\rightarrow \frac{1}{f}$ in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was trying to find an example showing that this statement does not always hold. If a sequence of positive measurable function $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure then $\frac{1}{f_n}$ converges to $\frac{1}{f}$ also in measure.

Can someone come up with one? :)

Comment: May be you should try giving examples $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure (forget about $\frac{1}{f_n}$)... Do you have some examples??

Comment: $f_n(x)=n\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should observe that there are no counter examples on spaces of finite measure (ignoring the problem of $f(x)=0$), because here we have $f_n \to f$ in measure iff for each subsequence of $(f_n)_n$, there is a further subsequence which converges a.e. to $f$.

So, let us consider the measure space $(1,\infty)$ with Lebesgue measure. Now consider $f(x)=1/x$ and

$$
f_n(x) = 1/x \cdot \chi_{(1,n)} + 1/n \cdot \chi_{[n,\infty)}. 
$$

I leave it to you to verify that this is indeed a counter example.